# ValueError when trying to run sanic in dev mode

Tags: python, sanic

I'm trying to run a server from the [sanic getting started example](https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/getting-started.html#hello-world-application), here is my code in `server.py`:

```py
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import text

app = Sanic("MyHelloWorldApp")

@app.get("/")
async def hello_world(request):
    return text("Hello, world.")
```

And when I run the default command `sanic server.app` everything is ok:

```
$ sanic server.app
[2021-12-31 17:08:21 +0700] [22196] [INFO] 
  ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │                        Sanic v21.12.0                       │
  │              Goin' Fast @ http://127.0.0.1:8000             │
  ├───────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┤
  │                       │     mode: production, single worker │
  │     ▄███ █████ ██     │   server: sanic                     │
  │    ██                 │   python: 3.9.4                     │
  │     ▀███████ ███▄     │ platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 │
  │                 ██    │ packages: sanic-routing==0.7.2      │
  │    ████ ████████▀     │                                     │
  │                       │                                     │
  │ Build Fast. Run Fast. │                                     │
  └───────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘

[2021-12-31 17:08:21 +0700] [22196] [WARNING] Sanic is running in PRODUCTION mode. Consider using '--debug' or '--dev' while actively developing your application.
[2021-12-31 17:08:21 +0700] [22196] [INFO] Starting worker [22196]
```

But when I try to run in dev mode it throws an error:

```
$ sanic --dev server.app
Starting in v22.3, --debug will no longer automatically run the auto-reloader.
  Switch to --dev to continue using that functionality.
c:\users\ev\repos\test-dashboard\venv\scripts\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for '__main__' (ValueError: __main__.__spec__ is None)
```

Should I add something to run sanic in dev mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't just run `sanic --dev server.app`.  I get the same error as you.

However, running `python -m sanic --dev server.app` does appear to work:

```
D:\StackOverflow\sanic>python -m sanic --dev server.app
Starting in v22.3, --debug will no longer automatically run the auto-reloader.
  Switch to --dev to continue using that functionality.
[2021-12-31 11:38:07 +0000] [7696] [INFO]
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │                         Sanic v21.12.0                         │
  │               Goin' Fast @ http://127.0.0.1:8000               │
  ├───────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │                       │        mode: debug, single worker      │
  │     ▄███ █████ ██     │      server: sanic                     │
  │    ██                 │      python: 3.7.3                     │
  │     ▀███████ ███▄     │    platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0 │
  │                 ██    │ auto-reload: enabled                   │
  │    ████ ████████▀     │    packages: sanic-routing==0.7.2      │
  │                       │                                        │
  │ Build Fast. Run Fast. │                                        │
  └───────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘

[2021-12-31 11:38:07 +0000] [7696] [DEBUG] Dispatching signal: server.init.before
[2021-12-31 11:38:07 +0000] [7696] [DEBUG] Dispatching signal: server.init.after
[2021-12-31 11:38:07 +0000] [7696] [INFO] Starting worker [7696]
```

I also get the text `Hello, world.` when opening `http://localhost:8000/` in a browser.

Comment: That is a little concerning to me. I have not seen or heard of this behavior before. Perhaps it is a window specific issue? Just curious, this is with a regular `pip install sanic`?

Comment: @AdamHopkins yes, this was with `pip install sanic`.  It may be a Windows-specific error.  I also had to modify `sanic/app.py` line 1556 (`task = loop.create_task(prepped, name=name)`) to remove the `name=name` parameter as that appears not to be supported on Python 3.7 and causes the server to fail to start.  I don't use Sanic myself, I only installed it to investigate this question.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will investigate from here.